# Installing an rm750i PSU to an Asus z170 Deluxe motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, gpu, computer-building

I have just bought a new PSU from Corsair, the rm750i.

I am afraid I might have connected the PSU in a wrong way. The [user manual](http://www.corsair.com/~/media/corsair/download-files/manuals/psu/rmi_manual.pdf) for the PSU is very vague and did not help.

So my question here is is there any difference between the red ports (8-pin)?
And is there any difference between the blue ports (6-pin)?

For example, in which port should I connect the CPU cable? Does it matter which of the red ports I connect it to?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "what side" of the connector?  You have a modular PSU, on one end you have the side that plugs into the PSU (only one side exists that does this, and its keyed, to the correct location) the other side is clearly the motherboard side.  The diagram you provided is clear?

Comment: @Arete There should be a "groove" and a latch that hangs onto the groove on one side only.

Comment: @Arete I have the same PSU, what you describe is odd, because it doesn't match my cable

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the problem.